# Why the middle tab of viewPager never call onCreateView for itself?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

For the 2 last days I spent all my time to try to find a solution to a strange problem in a viewpager with fragment. All fragment contains a listview (which has his own adapter).

Here is the situation :

- I have an activity which instantiate a viewpager and an adapter for it and contains the object adapter class.

public class SellerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seller);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpContainer2);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs2);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(SellerActivity.this,
                    "Selected page position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // Code goes here
        }

        // Called when the scroll state changes:
        // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            // Code goes here
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_shop, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    Intent i = new Intent(SellerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    if (id == R.id.action_home) {
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        mAuth.signOut();
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        return false;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return SellerFragment.newInstance(position + 1, "1");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "En Attente";
            case 1:
                return "En cours";
            case 2:
                return "Terminées";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

- I have then a fragment which looks like this :

public class SellerFragment  extends Fragment {

```
private String title;
private int page;

private AllOrders allOrders;

final List<CommandItemForSeller> orders = new ArrayList<>();
final LinkedHashMap<String, Order> saveOrders = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public SellerFragment(){

}

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static SellerFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
    SellerFragment fragmentFirst = new SellerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
    allOrders = new AllOrders();
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_seller, container, false);
    TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
    tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);

    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("orders");
    ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


            for (DataSnapshot orders : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String orderString = orders.getValue(String.class);

                //allOrders.addOrder(new Order(orderString, orders.getKey().substring(orders.getKey().length() - 4, orders.getKey().length())));
                saveOrders.put(orders.getKey(), new Order(orderString, orders.getKey().substring(orders.getKey().length() - 4, orders.getKey().length())));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    };

    myRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
    orders.clear();

    allOrders.clear();
    allOrders.addAllOrders(saveOrders.values());
    List<Order> selectedOrders = allOrders.getItemsOrderedByStatus(page);
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedOrders.size(); i++) {
        orders.add(new CommandItemForSeller(selectedOrders.get(i)));
    }

    CommandItemForSellerAdapter aa = new CommandItemForSellerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.pending_listview_item, orders);


    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.commandListView);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);


    return view;
}
```

As you can see each fragment calls content from Firebase Database so it remains asynchronous.

My problem is :

When I try  to load **"synchronous"** data (that I previsouly write in my code), list content is set by `onCreate` method at the first creation so each fragment for each tab get some content. However, the second tab never ever refresh for new data. 
So in a case of asynchronous, `onCreate` method doesn't return any data (due to the load time) and new datas should be added by the `onCreateView` (like a refresh) but for the second tab it never happens !

After many hours of debugging, I've just found out the following :

When I switch **from tab 1 to tab 2**, **fragment is rendered for tab 3**. When I switch **from tab 3 to tab 2, fragment is rendered for tab 1**. Even if the getItem(position) returns the right position for the tab, tab 2 now never calls `onCreateView` method and remains empty.

Please.. tell me why this projet behaves like that, I don't want to give up but I really don't understand what is the issue here.

If you need more specific information, tell me I can give you anything you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using FragmentPagerAdapter, ViewPager keeps adjacent pages "alive" (one to the left and one to the right) - meaning that when you have three fragments only, the second one will be never destroyed. You have to find a different way if you want to refresh data when fragments come into view - one idea is to add listener for page changes, using ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener method - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
Then, you can trigger refresh from within onPageSelected callback.

In your case, I think the simplest solution is to make SectionsPagerAdapter implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, store reference to each created Fragment (preferably WeakReference), and then call some refresh method on an appropriate SellerFragment instance.

Comment: Ok thank you, in my case I've chosen to add one tab. A little bit easier haha

Comment: @pablo432 I tried adding onPageChangeListener in ViewPagerAdpater (here sectionsAdapter). But i didnt got success. That is never called in the lifecycle. Can you help me out?

Comment: @malavshah share some code, then I'll take a look :)